# Unwind from modal VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I have the following structure of the app:

`[root VC] tabbar -> nvc1 -> vc1 -> vc2 -> [modal formsheet] nvc2 -> vc3`

What I want is to unwind from `vc3` to `vc2`. Basically `vc2` modally presents `nvc2` controller.

I logged the chain of calls to `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender`:

1. `vc3` calls `nvc2`
2. `nvc2` calls `tabbar`

So all I see is unwinding mechanism traverses only upwards, but the original controller that presented `nvc2` - `vc2` is within `tabbar > nvc1`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other implementations I have seen before, `canPerformUnwindSegueAction` cannot be reliably used to find the target controller in hierarchy where container controllers include other container controllers.

So additionally I use `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:` to drill down the road to find the target controller.

Worth to notice, it's iOS 8.0 related. iOS 7.1 finds target VC very fast without even asking tabbar.

```
- (UIViewController*)viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController withSender:(id)sender {
    for(UIViewController* vc in self.viewControllers) {
        // check if controller itself handles unwinding
        if([vc canPerformUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender]) {
            return vc;
        }

        // check if any child controller wants to handle this
        UIViewController* childVC = [vc viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];

        if(childVC) {
            return childVC;
        }
    }

    return [super viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];
}
```